# Firebase & CrashlyticsDelegate

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I want to detect if the last session crashed so I can attempt a recovery.

I got the CrashlyticsDelegate setup like this in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().delegate = self
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

(Crashlytics is initialized by Firebase)

This is the delegate method I'm using:

```
func crashlyticsDidDetectReport(forLastExecution report: CLSReport, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    print("FOUND CRASH")
    PXNAssistant.shared.recoverCrash()
    completionHandler(true)
}
```

Then I'm calling this to force a crash:

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

Tho, "FOUND CRASH" never gets printed...

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your code at first glance looks fine. where are you calling `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()`? if it is in the app delegate, perhaps it is not registering because the app delegate has not finished setting up firebase/crashlytics. you should use `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()` in places in your code where a crash may occur such as `force-unwrapping` or `do-try-catch` blocks. have you tried to implement Firebase's example code in your project?

```
import UIKit
import Crashlytics

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 50, width: 100, height: 30)
        button.setTitle("Crash", for: [])
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.crashButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @IBAction func crashButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
    }
}
```